# C language : why when input a float number in an int declared variable the result varries

Tags: c

using a simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, int **argv)
{
    int A, B, C, D, E, F; 
    printf ("input 1  : ");
    scanf ("%d", &A);
    printf ("input 2 : ");
    scanf ("%d", &B);
    C = A + B;
    D = A - B;
    E = A * B;
    F = A / B;
    printf ("sum  : %d\n", C);
    printf ("difference : %d\n", D);
    printf ("product  : %d\n", E);
    printf ("quotient : %d\n", F);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is as such, in the first scanf [p.s I know I can use other input methods its for a project] if you input a float/double number such as 1.3 or 20.5
the sum and difference are quite random for me,anyone can explain to me why the results are what they are?

Comment: What do you mean, "random"? What are the actual outputs that you're seeing?

Comment: If you enter a decimal point or exponent, the second scan fails where the first one did and the value in B is undefined.  Check that both scans are successful before using the values.

Comment: If you were checking the **return** of `scanf`, you may learn where you problem is....

Comment: its not a problem my kind sirs il answer one person each

Comment: Cody: for me it seems random cause each input returns a different output(like i said 1.2 or 20.5 as an example)
Jonathan : correct the second scan fails but assuming i input an interger first i still get B as a random number in my eyes
David : not quite a problem im curious for why this thing occurs i want a terminology so i can explain why this occurs

Result as an example : 
for 1.2 as A ,b gets undeclared ,returns for sum 33,difference -31,product : 32
for 20.5 as A,b gets undeclared,returns for sum 52,difference -12,product   640

Comment: @NektariosNeroid - You don't **initialize** any of your variables. They contain indeterminate values, and `scanf` doesn't change that because it fails. Why do you think you can expect *anything*?

Comment: i do not expect anything,my simple question is for the theory of c programming, how the result is explained when the first input in scan f is a float,and we force it on a  print f to print a %d

Comment: You fell victim to one of the classic blunders! The most famous of which is "never get involved in a land war in Asia," but only slightly less well-known is this: Always check the return value of `scanf` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, you must *always* validate *all* input (especially user input). All input functions provide a return. The `scanf` family returns the *match count*, the number of successful conversions processed based on the number of *format specifiers* in the *format string*. You use that to validate your input. E.g., at minimum:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, int **argv)
{
    int A, B, C, D, E, F; 
    printf ("input 1  : ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &A) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - A.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("input 2 : ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &B) != 1 || B == 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - B.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    C = A + B;
    D = A - B;
    E = A * B;
    F = A / B;
    printf ("sum  : %d\n", C);
    printf ("difference : %d\n", D);
    printf ("product  : %d\n", E);
    printf ("quotient : %d\n", F);
    return 0;
}
```

**note:** your `"quotient"` will always be the result of *integer division* and truncated accordingly.

Comment: my kind sir david , it doesnt need to be validated,its a mock program,my question for answer is,why when inputing a float or a double in an interger declared variable the result is as mentioned in the comments above,*edit*
oh thanks for explaining in the headline il study more on this then

Comment: Precisely because you are not validating it. When you enter `123.45` and attempt to use the `"%d"` format specifier, you read `123`. On the next read `.45` remains in `stdin` and you have a *matching failure*, nothing is read and all characters remain in the input buffer (e.g. `stdin`). `B` remains **Uninitialized** invoking **Undefined Behavior** when you attempt to access them. That's why you validate **all** input `:)`

Comment: so breaking it down,if we input 123.45 how it breaks down in the process of conversion to the result in the screen assuming we still force the %d
you just edit and answered my question hahaah

Comment: Attempting to read `123.45` with `"%d"` will read `123` as `A`, leaving `.45` to be read on the next call to `scanf`. Attempting to read `.45` with `"%d"` then fails. `B` remains uninitialized and you invoke *Undefined Behavior* from your first attempt to read from `B` from that point forward. What happens is Undefined. You can get garbage or you can Seg_Fault.

Comment: @NektariosNeroid -- note also the additional check that `B != 0`, otherwise `A/B` is undefined.

Comment: though so far i understand,i still havent exactly figured sir david how the .45 provokes such random results(i understand i mean that its due to failure durring the read) is .45 in the second read converted to its matching ascii numberical value?

Comment: The `.45` does nothing. It *happily* stays in the input buffer (`stdin`) just waiting for something to properly read it. `scanf ("%d", &B)` won't. It does nothing to `.45` -- that is the problem. `B` gets nothing and the value you use as `B` through the remainder of your code is **undefined**. You could call `scanf ("%d", &B)` 1000 times with `.45` in the input buffer, and it still wouldn't be read and `B` still wouldn't be defined.

Comment: @NektariosNeroid - the apparent **"randomness"** comes from the fact that the 4-bytes that make up `B` are never set to anything. They could just be the last garbage left in that particular memory location. Each time you run your code the address `B` gets most likely changes giving the appearance of random results.

Comment: mhm,last question then to make this the ending,"randomness" is that it returns different results per float input ,what i mean with that is that even if i input 100 times 10.5 it will return the same result but its not explained(i cant make sense out of it i mean).
so taking out the possibilty of memmory garbage(though its not unlikely)
what other scenario arrises?

Comment: `100 * 10.5` is an `int * double`. Rules of promotion will execute the multiplication as a `double`. If you then are assigning the results to an `int`, you are attempting to assign a *floating-point* number as an `int`. That will not work either. Floating point number are stored in *IEEE-754 floating point fomat*, not integer format. C has `types` for a reason. You can't make a salad out of them and expect things to work.

Comment: no my kind david when i meant 100 times 10.5 i dint mean it as the math one,i litteraly meant that if i input as a 10.5 100 times it will return the same result

Comment: It is apparent the very best advise I can give you is to always compile with *warnings enable*. Let the compiler help you find problem areas in your code. For `gcc`, that means adding `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile string. For `cl.exe` (e.g. VS on windoze) its `/Wall` (or `/W4` or `/W3` for less verbose warnings). Never accept code until it compile cleanly without warning.

Comment: @NektariosNeroid -- NO, NO, if you enter 100 time 10.5, you are still going to only get the garbage that is whatever the bytes in memory happened to be when you start your code. That's the issue, `B` just contains random garbage until it is properly initialized. `scanf ("%s", &B);` attempt to read `.anything` will never work and `B` still contains just random garbage which pollutes every computation you try and make with it..

Comment: i thank you then for clarifying that,i got my answer and much more info that i came for which i appreciate for,have a pleasant day

Comment: Keep at it. It just takes a while for it to all sink in. Learning C isn't a race. Enjoy learning each detail. Soon you will be the one helping others.

Answer (score 0):

The first `scanf()`, if the input has a decimal point will stop at the decimal point and leave it to be read on the next operation.   For input of `1.3`, this means `A` will get the value `1`, and the `.3` will remain in the input stream to be read.   This is because of the `%d` format - which tells `scanf()` to expect an integral value, and to stop on any characters that do appear in any representation of an *integral* value.   A decimal point is one such character that is not used in the representation of an integral value.

The next operation (`scanf("%d", &B)`) immediately encounters the decimal point and returns, without changing `B`.

Since `B` is not initialised at all (before, during, or after the `scanf("%d", &B)`) in the program, any subsequent attempt to access its value gives undefined behaviour.   Among other things, this can mean the value of `B` is indeterminate. From what you describe, for your setup, that results in "random" input.

If you're expecting to read input that looks like floating point values (e.g. that contains a decimal point) either read as floating point (e.g. `%f` format, and variables of a floating point type) or read a whole line (e.g. using `fgets()`) and check the contents of the line BEFORE trying to read integral values from it.

If you insist on using `scanf()`, check its return value.   On the second call of `scanf()` in your scenario, `scanf()` will return `0` rather than `1` (since it has read no values, rather than the one value the format string specified).   Which is an indication that something has gone wrong reading the input.